Jenkins job Permission Denied
I want to create a Jenkins job which runs a terrascript file for creating an EC2 instance. This job also runs an ansible-playbook for installing Tomcat on the new instance created. Here is a part of the main.tf file
resource "aws_instance" "my_vm" {
ami           = var.ami //Linux AMI
instance_type = var.instance_type
key_name      = "DevOpsKey_Licenta"

subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.terra_tomcat_sg.id]
associate_public_ip_address = true

tags = {
  Name = var.name_tag
}

 provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "echo ${aws_instance.my_vm.public_ip} >> /opt/infrastructure/inventory"
    } 
 }

and here is inventory file
[tomcat]

When the local-exec command runs it should write the ip adress in inventory file
When i run the Jenkins job i get this error
 [0m[1maws_instance.my_vm (local-exec):[0m [0mExecuting: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "sudo echo 
 3.81.123.86 > /opt/infrastructure-pipeline-terraform/inventory"]
 [0m[1maws_instance.my_vm (local-exec):[0m [0m/bin/sh: line 1: /opt/infrastructure- 
 pipeline-terraform/inventory: Permission denied
 [31m╷[0m[0m
 [31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mlocal-exec provisioner error[0m
 [31m│[0m [0m
 [31m│[0m [0m[0m  with aws_instance.my_vm,
 [31m│[0m [0m  on main.tf line 158, in resource "aws_instance" "my_vm":
 [31m│[0m [0m 158: provisioner "local-exec" [4m{[0m[0m
 [31m│[0m [0m
 [31m│[0m [0mError running command 'sudo echo 3.81.123.86 >
 [31m│[0m [0m/opt/infrastructure-pipeline-terraform/inventory': exit status 1. 
 Output:
 [31m│[0m [0m/bin/sh: line 1: /opt/infrastructure-pipeline-terraform/inventory:
 [31m│[0m [0mPermission denied
 [31m│[0m [0m
 [31m╵[0m[0m
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // stage
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // withEnv
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 ERROR: script returned exit code 1
 Finished: FAILURE


This file should be written in the current job workspace. The Pipeline code (absent from the question) may need to be updated for that, but the Terraform config definitely would need to be.

Does the directory /opt/infrastructure-pipeline-terraform exist already?

@stdunbar yes it exists.

@MatthewSchuchard i don't know if i understand how to do that :(

Specifying a relative path for the inventory file in the TF config would be a first step. The next step would be for the Pipeline code.

@MatthewSchuchard i modifed in main.tf the path of inventory as you said but now it writes me the ip address in another inventory file. And ansible said that is not matching hosts cuz the initial inventory file not having an ip adress
